# Calling invalidateOptionsMenu() inside Fragment using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-optionsmenu

Here is my code, firstly:

```
   @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        try {
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_user_search).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_view_spots).setVisible(false);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing; always null when looking at other people's profile
        }

    }
```

This happens inside a Fragment. I am using the newest `AppCompat` Theme as of this post.  I heard there is another way to call this, if you are using `AppCompat`, `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();`, but this is unrecognized.

What happens when I start app an go to this specific, `Fragment`, the `SearchView` Icon does appear, but does not respond to touch.  The second item above does not hide as suppose to.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT BY REQUEST**

This is called only in the `ActionBarActivity`, not the `Fragment`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:

            toggleSlidingMenu();

            return true;


        case R.id.action_view_spots:

            Intent mapLoc = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MapLocationsActivity.class);
            startActivity(mapLoc);

            return true;    


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Here is my XML**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_user_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Find User"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_view_spots"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Map View"/>    

</menu>
```

Comment: What's the code of your `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira I do not call it in the Fragment, but the `ActionBarActivity()` -- I will add it above

Comment: How is `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` unrecognized? It can only be called on a `ActionBarActivity/FragmentActivity`. Have you tried casting your `getActivity()` to one of those and call it?

Comment: @PedroOliveira  Yes I did use `getActivity()`; would it be because I am not using the ``Support Library for the `ListFragment`?  I am importing this: `import android.app.ListFragment;`

Comment: No that's not the case. After you call ` supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` your onPreparate is not called?. Also check if your onPreparate of your activity is not called too

Comment: I use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() from an ActionBarActivity (import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity).
You may be Mixing support library and regular classes. Make sure your references are all to the support libraries.
I once ran into a situation similar to your's. In my case it was a matter of my code calling things out of order.
I add my items to the menu with onCreateOptionsMenu and I do not use onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: Well, I changed my import of the `ListFragment` to the support library and now it recognizes the `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu `

Comment: use getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by importing the `ListFragment` directly from the Support Library.  Doing this allowed `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` to be recognized and then all worked well.